# Nav bar closely

Tags: html, css

I am designing a nav bar, which needs to be closed. This is simple html and css. I am attaching the design.
This is design it should look like :-

This is my current design :-

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>

      <div class="navbar">
        <div>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Menu link 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Menu link 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Menu link 3</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Menu link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "closed"?

Comment: The width of Nav bar need to be lesser than present. Please see the pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove from "a. nav" margin style:

```
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 2px;
```

here is your new navbar class

```
.navbar {
    height: 28px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin-top: 54px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

and example:  https://jsfiddle.net/sqhaqcoo/1/

to reduce button width change `padding: 8px 50px;` to `padding: 8px 40px;`

Comment: Still, nav bar is not reducing enough as per design.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a fixed `width:750px` to the `.navbar` and `margin:0 auto`, then reduce the `margin-left` and remove the `margin-right` for the a.nav like here:

```css
body{
    background-color: #dddddd;
    margin: 0;
                padding: 0;

            }
            h1{
                color:#7ba1cc;
                font-size: 20px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            table{margin: 0 auto;
                  margin-top: 20px;
                  width: 70%;
            }
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;

            }
            .black{
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            .body{
                width: 800px;
                height: 1000px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: #cccccc;

            }
            .header{
                height:115px;
                background-color: #1d8bb3;
            }
            .navbar{
                height:25px;
                padding-top:8px;
                margin-top:57px;  
                border: 1px solid red;
                width: 750px;  
                margin: 0 auto;

            }



            ul.nav, li.nav {
                display:inline-block;
                float: inside;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                
            }


            a.nav {
                background-color: #E2DDDD;
                padding: 8px 50px 8px 50px;
                margin-left: 5px;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-align:center;
            }

            a:hover.nav {
                background-color: #CCC8C8;
            }
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title> Homework 2</title>
        <meta charset= "UTF-8">
   </head>

    <body>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="header">
                <h1> Home Page </h1>
                <div class="navbar" >
                    <div>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Menu link 1</a></li>
                            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Menu link 2</a></li>
                            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Menu link 3</a></li>
                            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Menu link 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please reduce the width of each nav item?

Comment: Change the  `padding: 8px 50px 8px 50px;` to something smaller, then you need to find another width for the .navbar that will work for you. Test it out...